# Rails routes- get a form and post the results at the same url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, routes

I have a page /sessions that displays a form.

I want to to post to itself and then display the results.

My routes currently look like this

```
 namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users do
     match :all_users, :on => :collection, :as => "/users"
    end
    resources :sessions, :only => [ :index ]
    resources :user_info do
      match :user_info, :on => :collection
    end
    resources :user_schedule do
      match :user_schedule, :on => :collection
    end
end
```

so sessions now only shows the index, but I want it to respond to both get and post requests, and display my json results if it is a post request.

Eventually I'd like all other routes to follow the same

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
resource :sessions
```

Singular. That creates singular resources, as explained in [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

You still go to the different actions in the controller depending on the http method, so you can choose what to render in each case.

Comment: I actually ended up using a seperate get and post for each that I'll update my main post with.